# Flutter Async Function Update Doc and Use In Same Function

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have a function that does several things including update a document where the updated document is then used later on the in the function to update another set of documents. In this case the `ChallengesRecord challenge` is first updated by adding the current user to the challenge. Then, a second set of documents are updated by updating the list of users that are eventually sent a push notification through a collection called `ff_user_push_notifications`.

Everything seems to be working except the notifications record is not being updated with the updated `challenges` doc and pulling in data from the doc before it was updated. Here is what I have

```
Future<void> joinUserToChallenge(ChallengesRecord challenge) async {
 //this updates the ChallengesRecord challenge
 final challengesUpdateData = {
   'users_inchallenge': FieldValue.arrayUnion([currentUserReference])
 };
 await challenge.reference.update(challengesUpdateData).then((value) =>
 print('success'));

 //this then queries the notification documents to be updated then
 //iterates through them to update each one on a batch.commit()
 //however it is not using the updated challenges doc it appears
 final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('ff_user_push_notifications')
    .where(filter 1)
    .where(filter 2)
    .get().then((snapshots) => {
    snapshots.docs.forEach((doc) => {
 batch.update(doc.reference, {
    "user_refs" : challenge
    .usersInchallenge.map((u) => u.path).join(',')
     }),
 print(snapshots.docs.length)
  })
 });
 await batch.commit();
}
```

Console output below which suggests the challenge doc is being updated first.

```
flutter: success
flutter: 2
```

So it appears the `batch.update()` is not waiting on/using the updated `challenge` doc. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I also tried the code below, but it is still not working.

```
Future<void> joinUserToChallenge(ChallengesRecord challenge) async {
  //this updates the ChallengesRecord challenge
  final challengesUpdateData = {
    'users_inchallenge': 
 FieldValue.arrayUnion([currentUserReference])
 };
 await challenge.reference.update(challengesUpdateData).then((value) 
  => print('success'));

 final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('ff_user_push_notifications')
    .where(filter 1)
    .where(filter 2)
    .get();

 pushNotificiations.docs.forEach((doc) => {
   batch.update(doc.reference, {
   "user_refs" : challenge
   .usersInchallenge.map((u) => u.path).join(',')
  }),
 });
 await batch.commit()
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, but your code is hard to read because you're unnecessarily mixing `await` and `Future.then`.  There is no reason to use `.then` in the above code; just use `await` everywhere.  As you say, the console output indicates that your code *is* executing in the correct order. What is your evidence that it isn't?  Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @jamesdlin I had the second function outside of the `.then()` with the `await`, but that gave me the same result. I can see in the database that it is not updating. However, I have confirmed that it is pulling in the challenge doc, just not the one that is being updated previously in the function.